# How to call javascript function declared in the object scope?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
var john = {

    peter: {},

    one: function() { alert('one'); },

    two: function() {
        peter.handler = function() {
            one(); // JS cannot find one(). one() undefined.

            Console.log(this); // object peter
        }

        Console.log(this); // object john
    }
}
```

How can I use `one()` inside `peter.handler`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` to access the context of a function call, which is (typically) the object to which the function is assigned, but is explicitly specified at some point in the code (`HERE.method_name()` typically).

There is no way (short of looping over all your variables and testing) to get any idea about what other objects have `HERE` as the value of one of their properties.

The only way to identify `john` (which is a prerequisite for getting `one`) is to explicitly reference it from within the `two` or `handler` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with calling the javascript function by using Object **`john`** itself.

For Example :-

**`john.one();`**

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like that and call using john.one()

```
var john = {

    peter: {},

    one: function() { alert('one'); },

    two: function() {
        peter.handler = function() {
            john.one(); // JS cannot find one(). one() undefined.

            Console.log(this); // object peter
        }

        Console.log(this); // object john
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to access the parent object you should use the **this** keyword

see updated code below:

```
var john = {

    peter: {},

    one: function() { alert('one'); },

    two: function() {
        this.peter.handler = function() {
            one(); // JS cannot find one(). one() undefined.

            console.log(this); // parent object: peter
        };

        console.log(this); // object john
      this.one();
    }
};

john.two();
```

Comment: But `one` inside `this.peter.handler` will still be undefined. Did you actually try this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
var john = {

    peter: {},

    one: function() { alert('one'); },

    two: function() {
        this.peter.handler = function() {
            john.one(); // JS cannot find one(). one() undefined.

            console.log(this); // object peter
        }

        console.log(this.peter.handler()); // call peter handler
    }
}
```